# How to I return JsonResponse from Paginator's page? Object of type Page is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, jsonresponse

(this is my first stackoverflow question ever)

I want to return JsonResponse from the dictionary "context" (seems to be a paginator Page)
as coded below:

```
myposts = userposts.all().values()
myfollowers = userfollowers.ffollowers.all()
myfollowings = userfollowers.ffollowings.all()

context = {"posts": page_obj,
    "loops": range(1, totalpages + 1),
    "user": uprofile.username,
    "myposts": list(myposts),
    "mypostsnum": len(userposts.all()),
    "myfollowers": list(myfollowers),
    "myfollowersnum": len(userfollowers.ffollowers.all()),
    "myfollowings": list(myfollowings),
    "myfollowingsnum": len(userfollowers.ffollowings.all())
}
```

this is the return I use:

```
return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```

Result I get:

`Object of type Page is not JSON serializable`

My question is how do I get JsonResponse from 'context'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `"posts": page_obj`. `page_obj` is an instance of a model. Like `page_obj = Post.objects.get(pk=1)`.

`JsonResponse` will call `json.dumps()` on your context and is failing because it doesn't know how to handle a object.

I would recommend you to use [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for this. Serializers is used just for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to serialize querysets and django has predefined serializer that does the work.

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize

data = {
            'context': serialize("json", context)
        }
       
return JsonResponse(data)
```